# Report server Mondrian connection

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, mondrian, saiku, reportserver

I want to create new *Mondrian data source* (by using PostgreSQL) connection in Report-Server.

How can this be achieved?

I am not able to create Saiku reports using the Mondrian connection.

Comment: show the code what you tried so far and what failed.

Comment: I have created Mondrian datasource named Test.
When i am trying to create saiku report considering Mondrian datasource(Test).I am getting following error while select cube ("password authentication failed for user").